# IS it possible to assign a list view to a particular profile

Tags: profile, list-view, admin, system-admin

I have created a custom listview and now the requirement is only a particular profile to see that custom list view this particular profile shouldn't see the default list like all and recently viewed but only the custom list view should be available.

Can someone please confirm if this is possible?

Comment: What's the purpose behind your question? What you're asking for is not directly possible, but the underlying requirement probably is. Please read about [x-y problems](http://xyproblem.info/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your response the requirement is we got 2 profiles p1 and p2 and now we want p1 to see all the records but p2 should only see the active records

Could you please confirm if there is any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

No, You can't restrict a list view based on profile. There is an idea you can vote

[Restict Visibility on List Views by Profile](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdlJSUAZ/restict-visibility-on-list-views-by-profile)

Currently, you can only do this using role, group and territory.
[image]

Comment: We have a requirement  where we have 2 profiles p1 and p2 and now we want p1 to see all the records but p2 should only see the active records
 (active means where active__c checkbox is true)

Could you please confirm if there is any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: @gs650x You need to create separate groups for user and assign them list view. I don't see an easy way of doing it.